# Merge k sorted arrays of size n in O(nk) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, merge, heap

Recently in an interview I was asked this question:

> *Merge k sorted arrays each with n elements into a single array of size n*k in minimum time complexity.*

I gave a solution using a minheap of size k to find the minimum of the top elements of the k lists.

This way the time complexity would come down to - O(nklogk).

But he wasn't convinced. He wanted a solution with time complexity of O(nk).

I have searched on internet, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: For [comparison sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), it is not possible. Otherwise, you could use counting sort or bucket sort (for example).

Comment: @shx2 I was in acceptance with you answer, but since the interviewer had asked me the question, I was just waiting for some more answers/comments here.

Comment: Not sure if it's still relevant, I think the interviewer might have confused `n`. It's highly likely he thought `n` to be the number of elements in all `k` lists; and while describing the problem, he mentioned `n` to be length of each list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are right saying that the lower bound for any comparison sort is n*log(n) [where n is the the size of the array], there are sorting algorithms which can take less time.

As you have k sorted lists it is easy to find the minimum (call it m) and maximum (call it M) value of the lists you want to get at the end. Now you know that every element you need to sort is between m and M. So you can use Counting Sort which takes linear time. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort]

Hence, it takes O(k) to find m and M and then O(n*k) to sort the array. So the whole algorithm will take O(nk)

Comment: It is not O(n*k), it is O(n*k*(M-m)).  How well will it do for a very short input like: `[ [0], [9999999999999] ]`? There is nothing in the question to indicate you can make any assumptions about the values..  Also, it only works if the values are integers.  The question doesn't state that.  What if they are floats?

Answer (score 5):

He is wrong, you are right. Or perhaps this was a trick question.

If such a solution existed, you could sort any array of size K in O(K), which is proven to be impossible.

Here's how: you simply divide your array of size K into K singleton arrays, then apply your magic function.

The singleton arrays are all individually sorted of course. The complexity: O(K) for building the singleton arrays, and O(K*1) for merging (according to the assumption we refute).

Comment: He gave me a hint too. He said if all the arrays are of a variable length, such that there are N elements in k arrays. He said in that case  the time complexity will be O(Nlogk).          He further said  since you have a relaxation  that all the arrays are of fixed size n, You can  get some benefit out of it, and solve the problem with lesser no of comparisons

Comment: @ArpitAggarwal, I'm not sure what you're saying, but if the total number of elements is N*K, the best complexity is O(NKlogK), not O(NK). If it is N, the best complexity is O(NlogK), not O(N).  Re the relaxation, he is wrong, as my answer proves.