# Merge k sorted arrays of size n in less then O(nklogk) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, lower-bound

The question:

> Merge k sorted arrays each with n elements into a single array of size nk in minimum time complexity. The algorithm should be a comparison-based algorithm. No assumption on the input should be made.

So I know about an algorithm that solves the problem in nklogk time complexity as mentioned here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/.

Though, my question is can we sort in less than `nklogk`, meaning, the runtime is `o(nklogk)`.

So I searched through the internet and found this answer:
[Merge k sorted arrays of size n in O(nk) time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138441/merge-k-sorted-arrays-of-size-n-in-onk-time-complexity)

Which claims to divide an array of size K into singletons and merge them into a single array. But this is incorrect since one can claim that he found an algorithm that solves the problem in `sqrt(n)klogk` which is `o(nklogk)` but `n=1` so we sort the array in `KlogK` time which doesn't contradict the lower bound on sorting an array.

So how can I contradict the lower bound on sorting an array? meaning, for an array of size N which doesn't have any assumptions on the input, sorting will take at least NlogN operations.

Comment: *"So how can I contradict the lower bound on sorting an array?"*: which lower bound you want to contradict? And why do you think it should be contradicted?

Comment: lower bound on sorting an array, meaning, for an array of size N which doesn't have any assumptions on the input, sorting will take at least NlogN operations.

Comment: Yes, that is the lower bound. So my question is why do you want to contradict it?

Comment: "my question is can we sort in less than nklogk" No we can't. "So I searched through the internet and found this answer" The answer is not comparison based.

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound of `n log n` only applies to comparison-based sorting algorithms (heap sort, merge sort, etc.). There are, of course, sorting algorithms that have better time complexities (such as [counting sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/)), however they are not comparison-based.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm should be comparison-based, I didn't mention it.

Comment: Counting sort only has a "better" complexity under extra assumptions (namely, that the number of distinct possible values is known in advance and not too large). If you allow extra assumptions, then even comparison-based sorting algorithms can have better complexity. As a degenerate example, under the assumption "the input is already sorted", you can have a O(1) complexity ;-)

Comment: @linuxbegginer Well, in the case of comparison-based sorting algorithms, it's not possible to contradict the lower bound since it has been mathematically proven.

Comment: Where exactly it has been mathematically proven? 
Plus, no assumptions have been made regarding the numbers appearing in the array. 
So no counting sort or any sort that use assumptions on the input.

Comment: @linuxbegginer You can find the proofs online. A quick googling gives me [this](https://tildesites.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall07/Lectures/sortLB.pdf) and [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf).

Comment: But that's not what I am asking for... you said there is a lower bound proof for the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: @linuxbegginer I'm not really good at proofing things. But let me put it this way: the lower bound for comparison-based sort algorithm is o(nlogn). One of such algorithm is merge sort. The solution in the geeksforgeeks article that gives nklogk time complexity is actually a variation merge sort algorithm that starts at halfway of the original merge sort (since the array is partially sorted). So for nklogk is indeed the lower bound for that problem in the case of comparison-based sorting algorithms.